# Create Set (String) variable of unique values occuring in a Column grouped by Identification Column

Tags: r, set, aggregate, dplyr

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c("1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4"), Product=c("A", "B", "B", "A", "C", "C", "A", "B", "C", "C"))
```

I would like to get a Set of values of column 'Product' grouped by the column 'ID'.
The Set should be a string delimited by a comma. It should represent a string value where each possible combination of Product values occurs just once.
The outcome is unique ID values with possible combinations of Product values  without value repetition.

My approacch that gets me half the way is:

```
library(dplyr)
df2<-df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(Set = toString(unique(Product)))
```

Output:
     ID     Set
    (fctr)   (chr)
1    A, B
2    B, A
3       C
4 A, B, C

The output is a string variable Set that has the combinations of values of variable Product however they can repeat itself, that is A, B != B, A which is undesirable.
I would like to use a function that would allow my workflow to get a Set variable where A, B = B, A etc, hence also the Product Frequencies will consequently match a different rule.

Expected output:
ID Set (fctr) (chr) 1 A, B 2 A, B 3 C 4 A, B, C so when I do summary statistics it will show that value A, B is in the data set 2x (as compared to A, B 1 time and B, A 1 time)

Who knows?

Comment: Output: ID Set (fctr) (chr) 1 A, B 2 A, B 3 C 4 A, B, C
so when I do summary statistics it will show that value A, B is in the data set 2x (as compared to A, B 1 time and B, a 1 time)

Comment: Please update it iin your post as it difficult to understand from the commments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sort` in between to `sort` the 'Product' within each 'ID'

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(Product = toString(unique(sort(Product))))
#     ID Product
#  (fctr)   (chr)
#1      1    A, B
#2      2    A, B
#3      3       C
#4      4 A, B, C
```

---

An alternative using `data.table` syntax would be

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, list(Product = toString(unique(sort(Product)))) , by = ID]
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
aggregate(Product~ID, df,FUN= function(x) toString(unique(sort(x))))
```

Comment: Seems to work, simple but effective solution, thnx @akrun

Comment: Always used `paste(collapse = ", ")` never knew `toString` was a base R function +1.